# Redraw issue in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this issue and has a fix for it? The problem is with VS 2012 Ultimate where when it has been minimised or the lock screen has covered it it appears as shown in the attached screenshot.

This is the only application on my system (Dell E6510 running Windows 8) that exhibits these symptoms so I'm inclined to lay the blame at the application's feet rather than the system.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing around with the following settings appears to have resolved the issue for me. Your kilometerage may vary[image: VS2012 settings]

Comment: If I check then uncheck any of those options it works until I close it, then you have to repeat again next time

Answer (score 0):

If I check then uncheck any of those options it works until I close it, then you have to repeat again next time.

So did more research and found this mentioned on MS Connect site...

"I had a quick look at the "Extensions" running in VS2012, and noticed one I remember magically appearing without me really asking for it. HDInsightTools for Azure."

I removed that and all works! :)  So maybe you need to review Extensions installed?

Comment: Thanks @Darren, I'm now running on VS2013 and awaiting VS2015 so am not going to go back to VS2012 to test this. Other people still on 2012 though may find it useful so thanks for your help.